# problem with a palindrome method

Tags: java

Hi i am trying to write a palindrome method but am getting the wrong results

```
public static boolean isPalindrome(String input){
    int b=input.length();
    int []array=new int[b];
    for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
        array[i]=Integer.parseInt(input);}


        for(int i=0;i<(array.length)/2;i++){
            if(!(array[i]==array[array.length-1-i])){
                    return false;}
        }

        return true;

    }
}
```

Comment: What test cases are you using? Are you getting the wrong results on all test cases or only some of them? Do the test cases that are failing have anything in common?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can go for the simpler method to check for palindrome.

Use the StringBuilder class and use the `.reverse()` method to reverse the string and then check for palindrome test.

```
StringBuilder value1= new StringBuilder("nitin");
StringBuilder value2 = input.reverse();

if(value1.toString().equals(value2.toString()){
    System.out.println("This is a palindrome string ..");
}
```

Or you can go by this way also ..

```
public static boolean isPalindrome(String word) {
    int left  = 0;                 
    int right = word.length() -1;  

    while (left < right) {         
        if (word.charAt(left) != word.charAt(right)) {
            return false;          
        }
        left++;                    
        right--;                   
    }

    return true;                   
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you put the String into a `StringBuilder` you can use the `.reverse()` method. then just check if the 2 are equal.

```
 StringBuilder input = new StringBuilder("helloolleh");
    StringBuilder value = input.reverse();

    if(value.toString().equals(input.toString()){
    //process
    }
```

Comment: Not optimal in terms of running time

Comment: @chrislegend there's something to be said for readability though, depending on how frequently the function will be used

Comment: Agreed, but I'd choose the fast algorithm with a few comments over the readable one any day. Like you said, it depends on use, so this is a good answer in some respects.

Comment: @chrislegend if your running this method a few times, its not that big of a deal but i agree once you hit the higher frequencies another algorithm would be better

Answer (score 3):

Not sure why you are using `Integer.Parse()`.

Try something like this (mostly following the logic from the question)

```
public static boolean isPalindrome(String input) {
    char[] array = input.toCharArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < (array.length) / 2; i++) {
        if (!(array[i] == array[array.length - 1 - i])) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: thanks but can you please tell me why the method i wrote did not work

Answer (score 3):

You can use two "pointers" one starting from the beginning of the string and one from the end, and move them in opposite directions checking that characters are equals; as soon as you find a difference you know your string is not palindromic; conversely, if you don't find differences you know the string is palindromic:

```
public static boolean isPalindome(String input) {
    char[] cs = input.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0, j = cs.length - 1; i < j; i++, j--) {
        if (cs[i] != cs[j])
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test_String {

private static boolean IsPalindrome(String s)
{
    StringBuffer str1 = new StringBuffer(s);
    StringBuffer str2 = str1.reverse();

    if(s.equalsIgnoreCase(str2.toString()))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter a String to be checked as Palindrome ");
String in = scan.nextLine();
    if(IsPalindrome(in))
        System.out.println("\nEntered String is a Palindrome ");
    else
        System.out.println("\nEntered String is NOT a Palindrome ");
}

}
```